# Build Makefile Target in Bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to build `openssl` with bazel. Here is my current setup

In my `/WORKSPACE` in the project root i have

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "openssl",
    urls = ["https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1c.tar.gz"],
    sha256 = "f6fb3079ad15076154eda9413fed42877d668e7069d9b87396d0804fdb3f4c90",
    strip_prefix = "openssl-1.1.1c",
    build_file = "@//:BUILD.openssl",
)
```

In my `/BUILD.openssl` file i have

```
genrule(
    name = "build",
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
    srcs = glob(["**"]),
    cmd = '\n'.join([
        './Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc -mmacosx-version-min="10.14" --prefix=$@ --openssldir=$@',
        'make',
        'make install',
    ]),
    outs = ["openssl"],
)
```

I don't quite understand what folder I am in while this `genrule` is running, since it complains with

```
/bin/bash: ./Configure: No such file or directory
```

Also what do i specify for `srcs` and `outs` in a makefile target?
What directory would i specify for openssls `--prefix` and `--openssldir` in this case?

I'm kind of suprised that integrating targets that are not configured in Bazel is so poorly documented, given that's probably the most important use case.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`rules_foreign_cc`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc) to integrate with `make`-based projects. Based on information in [this bug,](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/issues/254) I got a basic openssl build working:

In your `WORKSPACE`, add:

```py
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

# Group the sources of the library so that rules in rules_foreign_cc have access to it
all_content = """filegroup(name = "all", srcs = glob(["**"]), visibility = ["//visibility:public"])"""

http_archive(
    name = "openssl",
    build_file_content = all_content,
    sha256 = "f6fb3079ad15076154eda9413fed42877d668e7069d9b87396d0804fdb3f4c90",
    strip_prefix = "openssl-1.1.1c",
    urls = ["https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1c.tar.gz"],
)

# Rule repository
http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    sha256 = "7b350ba8b2ef203626fda7572506111e3d5286db92de3ecafdcbc99c6c271265",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-16ddc00bd4e1b3daf3faee1605a168f5283326fa",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/rules_foreign_cc-16ddc00bd4e1b3daf3faee1605a168f5283326fa.zip",
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//:workspace_definitions.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()
```

In your `BUILD` file, add:

```py
load("@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:configure.bzl", "configure_make")

configure_make(
    name = "openssl",
    configure_command = "config",
    configure_options = [
        "no-shared",
    ],
    lib_source = "@openssl//:all",
    static_libraries = [
        "libssl.a",
        "libcrypto.a",
    ],
)
```

Finally, run `bazel build`:

```
$ bazel build :all
INFO: Analyzed target //:openssl (1 packages loaded, 1 target configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
INFO: From CcConfigureMakeRule openssl/include:
Target //:openssl up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/openssl/include
  bazel-bin/openssl/lib/libcrypto.a
  bazel-bin/openssl/lib/libssl.a
  bazel-bin/copy_openssl/openssl
  bazel-bin/openssl/logs/Configure_script.sh
  bazel-bin/openssl/logs/Configure.log
  bazel-bin/openssl/logs/wrapper_script.sh
```

Comment: I need to be able to export an environment variable during build (`export OSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET="10.14"`) or the resulting library does not have the required `LC_VERSION_` set. I solved it with a custom `genrule` now, is it possible to export a var in `configure_make`?

Comment: Perhaps the `configure_env_vars` attribute? https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/blob/16ddc00bd4e1b3daf3faee1605a168f5283326fa/examples/cc_configure_make/BUILD#L18

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Tried that. I went back to a normal `genrule`.

Answer (score 0):

Please see https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/issues/337 for more details...